# Default Required Device Capabilities For cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, info.plist

For some reason, cocos2d's default Info.plist contains `accelerometer` and `opengles-1` as required device capabilities. Why is this - surely all iOS devices have these capabilities and so this is unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact these entries are optional for cocos2d based apps on all iOS devices to date.

However it seems like a good idea to include these two from a perspective of the framework itself. Cocos2d internally expects the device to have an accelerometer and OpenGL ES 1.1 support because it makes use of these frameworks without checking for their existence.

And you never know when Apple might decide to include Apple TV as a deployment device for iOS apps. The Apple TV certainly wouldn't support the accelerometer framework.

Comment: Good point about the Apple TV (or any other iOS device). Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Cocos2D 2.0 beta still sets opengles-1 in its Info.plist. Anyone using Cocos2D 2.0 is well advised to change that to opengles-2 and maybe also add armv7 as a requirement, because all armv6 devices don't support opengles-2 either.